# WPF - MenuItem Icon using data templates

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, menuitem

I have a menuitem with an itemsource set to a collection of **differing** types. For each type, I have defined a datatemplate within the resource section.

How do I go about setting the menuItems Icon depending on the datatype?

Edit : Whilst the ideas suggested by Brian would have worked, I didn't want the viewmodel to be specifying the image resource itself, but rather a tag for the View to switch on, and so went for the following.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Process}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Usage}" Value="UsageA">
                    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource imgA}"/>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Usage}" Value="UsageB">
                    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource imgB}"/>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Usage}" Value="UsageC">
                    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource imgC}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Can this be done with a template selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a `Style` for the `MenuItem`'s `ItemContainerStyle`.  In the style, you can bind the `Icon` for the `MenuItem` to a property on your object.  It would look something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="MyMenuItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
   <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding MenuName}"/>
   <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MenuCommand}"/>
   <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding MenuIcon}" />
 </Style>
```

You could also do this in the `DataTemplate` by using a Horizontal `StackPanel` and just displaying both an Image and the Text for the menu, but that won't really be utilizing the `Icon` property of the `MenuItem`, that will just be adding an image to the `Content` of the `MenuItem`.

The `ItemContainerStyle` defines the container for the `MenuItem`, and allows you to assign the `Icon` property of the `MenuItem`.